# How to wrap textview to relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, imageview

Im trying to wrap my textview into a relative layout which has an image. Everytime I reload (retreieve string data from db) my textview expands beyond the relative layout (using wrap content). So I want to know how I can put the textview on the relative layout without it expanding too much.

I would like a scroll bar on the relative layout so I can scroll down to see the textview in the un-changeable relative layout.

Comment: Can you post your xml layout? An image showing the problem would help, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set maximum lines of textview in xml so it is not expanding beyond that...

Suppose textview maximum lines is 5

```
<TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="3"/>
```

Comment: thanks this may be the only option. I will leave it a little longer before I confirm. but its not very efficient.